# Equation involving cosine

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I don't really know how to crack this one. Any help appreciated. $$\cos\left(d\sqrt{4-d^2}\right)=-\frac{d}2$$ Why is MSE forcing me to write more? Jeez.

Comment: Have you tried guessing?

Comment: Up voted for the last remark. Regarding the question, is this part of a bigger problem? If it is, you should add it to the question.

Comment: This last remark is hilarious. For future reference, you just add `{}{}{}{}{}` empty brackets in the $\rm \TeX$

Comment: @GitGud Yes, I'm solving a bigger problem, but I won't post it as a question. I just want to know if such an equation can be solved or not. If not, I'll try a different approach.

Comment: @Sabyasachi Thanks, didn't know that.

Comment: alt+0173 is better

Comment: One solution is -2

Comment: @Awesome In all your awesomeness, you misspelled *awesomeness* in your profile.

Comment: @Awesome Indeed, -2 is the only solution. Just checked the graph on a plotter, and it was obvious.

Comment: I don't understand.

Comment: @Sabyasachi Google graph says 2 solutions. I don't think our graphs ever match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Sabyasachi wrote, the domain is $d\in [-2,2]$. Obviously $d=-2$ is a solution but there  is another one between $-2$ and $0$ which cannot be expressed analytically (I suppose). So the solution must be found using numerical methods such as Newton, provided a reasonable starting point. By inspection, the value of $$f(d)=\cos\left(d\sqrt{4-d^2}\right)+\frac{d}2$$ is negative for $d=-1$ and positive for $d=0$.

So, start iterating at $d=- \frac {1} {2}$ and update $d$ according to $$d_{new}=d_{old}-\frac {f(d_{old})}{f'(d_{old})}$$ The successive iterates on Newton method will then be $-0.659241$, $-0.654719$ which is the solution for six significant digits.

Comment: @Klobbbyyy. You are welcome !